# Where to put adverbs of manner?

Tags: prepositions

I assume that *basically* is an adverb of manner and I am not sure where to put it in the sentence below

> This table was made out of wood basically.

Comment: I'd leave it out altogether since it doesn't add any meaning.

Comment: I know the sentence is a bit silly but assume that I need an adverb of manner in such a sentence so in which position should I put it?

Comment: @KillingTimeYOur comment would be a lot more funny and demonstrative if after meaning you put ", really."

Comment: I don't find your example sentence to be grammatical.  It would be grammatical if there were a comma before "basically", reflecting the fact that the main sentence stress is on "wood", and in this case, "basically" is clearly not a manner adverb.  It doesn't mean "in a basic manner".  Real manner adverbs take main stress at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Table manner adverbs go between salad fork and the bread plate with the -ly inward ;)

Comment: Which sense have you in mind? **(1)** The bottom line is that this table was made out of wood. //  **(2)** This table was made out of like wood. (filler usage) //  **(3)** This table was made largely out of wood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that *basically* here is more of a *[comment adverb](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode85/languagepoint.shtml)* than an adverb of manner. Comment adverbs are most common in the front position or the mid-position.

> - Basically, this table was made out of wood.
> - This table was basically made out of wood.

You can put *basically* at the end, but then it tends to come across as an afterthought:

> - This table was made out of wood, basically.

An adverb of manner is most often found in mid-position. But, unlike a comment adverb, it is more common at the end than the beginning:

> - This table was quickly made out of wood.
> - This table was made out of wood quickly.
> - ?Quickly this table was made out of wood.

Comment: I've not found a supporting reference, but I'm fairly sure that 'basically', like 'essentially',  _can_ have the sense 'for the main part'; I'm having trouble seeing this as either a manner or a comment usage. It's a limiting modifier.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Very often "basically" has no meaning at all, simply serving as a nervous speech filler. "It's raining, basically", "My name's Jim, basically". This table example looks very much the same thing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. _Collins Cobuild English Grammar_ (p421) lists _basically_ (along with _essentially, broadly, ultimately_, etc.) as a generalizing _sentence adjunct_: 'You often want to avoid making a firm, forceful statement, because you are aware of facts that do not quite fit in with what you are saying. One way of doing this is to use a sentence adjunct which indicates that you are making a general, basic, or approximate statement.' Other grammars may categorize it as a _limiting modifier_, but it is certainly not an adverb of manner in this context.

Comment: @Shoe You make a very valid point. But it becomes something that is used to excess by someone lacking confidence.

Comment: **I'm not contesting** the pragmatic-marker subclass _summarising_ (= 'the bottom line is, ...') or (as @WS2 adds) subclass _filler_ (= '[er] like', with adjusted placement) usages. But you're missing the alternative possibility: << **basically** _adverb_: (b) for the most part [,largely] _they basically play zone defense_ / [_It is [made] basically [of] wood, with a bit of chrome-plated steel_] >> [M-W]. Compare 'partly'; 'totally'. And I'm saying that _this_ usage is the one I'm having difficulty fitting into the 'manner' slot. Degree, probably.

Answer (score 0):

In his book *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*, McCawley proposes that manner adverbs are modifiers of the VP (or perhaps V'), and he also remarks that in many languages, a normal position for any modifier is before or after the constituent it modifies.  Taken together, these claims imply that manner adverbs will either come before or after the VP that they modify.

McCawley's theory is not sufficient to describe the positions of English adverbs in general, as he would have readily conceded.  But in the case of manner adverbs, it works well enough to be worth mentioning.